# Is there a reason to not use a guard check using params instead of singular checks?

Tags: c#

I've been refactoring guard statements for my project to simply use a custom Ensure class with 2 methods. Some methods require multiple null checks and I implemented a guard method that simply accepts a list. This method will call the singular guard check for each value given. However I don't seem to find any other examples of this done and was wondering if there was a reason for this.

The guard methods:

```
public static void ArgumentNotNull(object argument, string argumentName)
{
    if (argument == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(argumentName);
    }
}

public static void ArgumentsNotNull(params object[] arguments)
{
    foreach(object argument in arguments)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(argument, nameof(argument));
    }
}
```

A call would then look like:

```
Ensure.ArgumentsNotNull(value1, value2, value3);
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: My recollection may be wrong, but doesn't `nameof` return the static name of its argument - that is, it will return the string `"argument"`, since that is the name of the variable that is passed in?

Comment: @Steve True actually. This is probably the reason. Cheers!

Comment: Doesn't C# now have nullable reference types, which solves this problem at the type-system level?

Comment: @Alexander: introducing nullable reference types into a large existing code base can be pretty hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong with this approach?

There's nothing wrong, per se, but nullability is not the only guard that exists. When you start accounting for all possible guards, especially when you get to compound evaluations (`x == null || x.IsActive`), making prefabs for every check is a bit futile.

In really, all you've really done here is rephrase an evaluation `x != null` with the English `IsNotNull(x)`, which to any developer (who is not still learning the ropes) reads the same and doesn't really improve the readability.

If you had a **non-trivial** bit of custom logic that needed to be used all across the codebase (e.g. validating a credit card number), I'd be on board with your idea. But this example is IMHO too trivial to warrant an extra abstraction.

---

That being said, in testing this is something that is done. `Ensure.ArgumentsNotNull` is pretty much identical to the existing `Assert.NotNull`. However, `Assert` is tailored towards specifically throwing assertion exceptions that test runners capture.

Comment: The codebase is decently large and is cluttered with:
```if (sampleValue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sampleValue));```

Some methods having up to four checks. This was basically only meant for nullchecks. Whenever a specific class related check has to be done (i.e. Active), ofcourse a different approach will be taken.

Comment: @M.Mayhem: There are different abstraction approaches here. By itself, I do not think a single evaluation warrants abstraction. A set of them? Maybe. But I'd be inclined to abstract that privately in the class itself (some sort of `private void Validate(...)` method) as opposed to abstracting it. You might also want to look into a dedicated validation library, as opposed to rolling your own. That being said, what you're doing isn't particularly _wrong_, it's just that it often ends up not being worth the effort of doing so. If you think it's worth the effort, then by all means.

Comment: The problem is related to a project with multiple methods within the same class requiring a validation check. I think in this project, the Validate solution as private methods would not be the right approach, but I'll keep it in mind for future projects. Thank you very much. I was just worried I was overlooking something as I don't see it done. I'm also with you on dont reinvent the wheel, but I prefer not to depend on a library for something as simple as this.

Comment: @M.Mayhem _"I'm also with you on dont reinvent the wheel, but I prefer not to depend on a library for something as simple as this."_ I get where you're coming from and I do agree with it up to a point. But it is ironically the same line of thinking as to why I don't think it warrants an abstraction to begin with, i.e. because it's too simple.

Comment: I just don't like looking at 4 rows of the line in my first comment and would rather have a more clean and consise looking guard statement without using private methods for each method that requires a guard statement. But maybe you are right.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Yes... it doesn't work. Just test it.

```
Ensure.ArgumentsNotNull(value1, value2, value3);
```

If you call it like this, and for example `value2` is null, you will get an Exception telling you that your parameter "argument" is null. Because that is what `nameof(argument)` does. It returns "argument". It does not magically return the actual name of the parameter that was passed.

In the future, if you want to know if something works, I suggest writing a unit test for it. That is the easiest way to find out.

Comment: This answer is correct. However, I think it would be a little bit more polite not only to assess the code which does not work, but also the part of the code which works.

Comment: Well, in context of the question "using params instead of..." it really doesn't matter how much of it works, when the central piece doesn't. I don't mean to be rude, but I don't see how "the rest of it works fine" would help either.

Comment: Depends how you define "works".  If "works" means "prevents the code from running with null parameters", the OP's approach _does work._

There is no _requirement mentioned in the question_, to return a user friendly Exception.  I agree that would be nice.  And some simple reworking of the `Ensure.ArgumentsNotNull()` code could easily return at least the index of the bad argument.

Comment: @user949300 I would assume "works" means "throws an `ArgumentNullException` with the argument name as parameter", as obviously intended and as is best practice.